# How to defer or load an A-Frame scene programmatically?

Tags: aframe

I have an A-Frame scene that I want to place on a page, but I want it to load only when I tell it to. That means it should not be rendering or running until I emit an event or call a method.

```
<body>
  <!-- Don't play yet. -->
  <a-scene>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is currently no built-in + documented way, but there will be a feature for this later. However, there are a couple ways to do this manually:

### Create `<a-node>`

Nodes (which every `<a-entity>` inherits from will block the scene from loading until it calls the `.load()` event.

Create a dummy node in the scene. and call `.load()` when ready.

```
<a-node id="dummy"></a-node>

document.getElementById('dummy').load();
```

#### Leverage asset system

You can create an asset that will never load until you tell it to, and set the timeout to effectively indefinite (later we will add a feature to not timeout).

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets timeout="999999999">
    <a-asset-item id="trigger" src="NEVERLOADUNTILITELLITTO.whatever"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>
</a-scene>
```

Then trigger.

```
document.querySelector('#trigger').load();
```

### Inject scene only when ready

You could keep your scene in a separate file, template, or as a string, or using a framework with concept of Views. Only inject the scene into the DOM when you are ready for it to render. This is the most work, but currently the most air-tight method.

`sceneEl.appendChild(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(str));`

#### Pause the scene as soon as you can

This will pause the scene from rendering. However, the scene will probably have initialized some components and rendered a few frames already. So it is not air-tight.

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').pause();
```

Comment: I just tried the third way and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by air-tight?

Comment: Re: "Leverage asset system", I do not understand what is causing the asset to "never load". Is it the timeout? why would a large timeout lead to never loading?